# using die/exit/return inside codeigniter sql transaction

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using SQL Transactions in codeigniter.
As per documentation, manual transaction are done as given below.

```
$this->db->trans_begin();

$this->db->query('UPDATE ...'); // SQL 1
$this->db->query('SELECT ...'); // SQL 2
$this->db->query('SELECT ...'); // SQL 3

if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
{
    $this->db->trans_rollback();
}
else
{
    $this->db->trans_commit();
}
```

Now my question is what will happen, If I put a die/exit statement within SQL1 and SQL2? If I want to return false, depending upon SQL1. Do i need to put $this->db->trans_rollback() before returning false? What is the best practice of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to achieve. If you want your SQL1 to execute anyway, you should do trans_commit() and then return FALSE. So it all depends on the logic of your website.

Anyway, normally, it should be trans_commit() or trans_rollback() before the end.